# Why when downloading the ubuntu 13.10 the server downloading the old version of ubuntu 12.04.3?

Tags: downloads

Can any one helping me, please?
Why when downloading the ubuntu 13.10 the server downloading the old version of ubuntu 12.04.3?

Comment: Sounds like you have javascript disabled or you use an addon like noscript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official download link [Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/)